# gulp 3 upgrade to gulp 4 tasks did not complete: prod, compile

Tags: typescript, gulp

I am in the process of upgrading Gulp from version 3 to 4 . I am getting this error about this `task did not complete`. Is there anything I need to change this in the compile task for version 4 of gulp? I dont think its correct to add an `async` to the async gulp.series "clean" task.

console

```
[09:33:16] Using gulpfile C:\WebProjects\ITF\ITF.Web\Gulpfile.js
[09:33:16] Starting 'prod'...
[09:33:16] Starting 'compile'...
[09:33:16] The following tasks did not complete: prod, compile
[09:33:16] Did you forget to signal async completion?
Process terminated with code 1.
```

gulp

```
    gulp.task("prod", gulp.series(
            "compile",
            "bundle",
            "min",
    ));
    
    gulp.task('clean', function () {
        return gulp.src(paths.dist, { read: false }).pipe(rimraf({ force: true }));
});

    gulp.task("compile", () => gulp.series("clean", function () {
        return gulp.src("./App/**/*.ts")
            .pipe(inlineNg2Template({
                base: "/",                  // Angular2 application base folder
                target: "es6",              // Can swap to es5
                indent: 2,                  // Indentation (spaces)
                useRelativePaths: false,     // Use components relative assset paths
                removeLineBreaks: false,     // Content will be included as one line
                templateExtension: ".html", // Update according to your file extension
                templateFunction: false    // If using a function instead of a string for `templateUrl`, pass a reference to that function here
            }))
            .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
            .pipe(ignore("References.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/App"))
            .on("finish", function () {
                console.log("Results finish");
                console.log(gulp.src);
            })
            .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); });
    }));
```

Comment: I found upgrading from 3 to 4 to be pretty intensive and had to make a lot of changes. It is a lot more sensitive to not having something 100% correct for making sure something is "done".  [Async Completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion) might help (see Using an error-first callback with a "cb" to call to signal "done").

Comment: so in the `task clean` I would return `done`?

Comment: An example - `function x(done) { /* ... */ done(); }`. Gulp will pass in a "completed" function automatically, and if you use it you can call it to indicate work is complete. This could be in an `.on` or inside a callback to another function, etc.

Comment: You don't need this `() => `  in the `compile` task.  I would guess that the following `return` is just to the arrow function and is not signaling task completion to the actual task function.

Comment: @Mark great eye! That is likely the culprit. `gulp.task("compile", gulp.series("clean", function () {` might do the trick.